# Can anyone identify this woman’s uniform?

Tags: world-war-one, united-kingdom, identification, uniform, women

Found this photo in a box of family pictures from England.  Most photos were prior to WW1[image]

Comment: Suspect it may well be a school or university.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like it may match [Felsted School](http://www.britishunited.net/en/seminar/felsted-school/)s symbol. Wikipedia entry [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felsted_School).
[image]
There seems to be indications of earlier Felsted schools which did have women or girls in attendance. [Felsted house](https://books.google.com/books?id=n2cbAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA511&dq=felstead+teacher-training+college&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1u4KIqLDiAhWXJzQIHUgMC4oQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=felstead%20teacher-training%20college&f=false) had a practising School which had 90 girls attending.

> Practising Schools Two immediately opposite the college One for 90
>   girls and one for 120 infants Both reported very efficient and under
>   the control and supervision of the college authorities

The practising school seems to have been prep for [another school](https://www.british-history.ac.uk/vch/oxon/vol4/pp442-462).

> the schools became practising schools for Felstead Teacher-Training
>   College, which had started in 1876 at no. 23 Banbury Road. Even so the
>   boys' schools closed in 1885; the girls' and infant schools, sometimes
>   called Felstead House Practising schools, continued under the
>   management of the college, but in other respects were considered as
>   public elementary schools supervised by the school committee of the
>   parish. (fn. 190) In 1923 the two schools were reorganized under one
>   headmistress. (fn. 191) The site was purchased by the university in
>   1936, the school closed, and the 40 children transferred to the
>   convent school in St. Philip and St. James parish. (fn. 192)

So it appears early forms of Felstead schools were in operation until 1935, well within the time frame of this photo.

---

Going at this from a heraldry angle, one other little thing seems to coincide with the symbol in the Photo. The  [Felsted School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felsted_School#History)

> was founded in 1564 by Richard Rich, 1st Baron Rich (also known as
>   Riche)

[Richard Rich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Rich,_1st_Baron_Rich), the first Baron Rich, had the following arms:

[image]

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article, Felsted only admitted girls between 1970-1989, so unless the date of the photograph is wrong, I don't see how. The insignia does appear to match.

Comment: Sorry, been away from the computer. Symbol seems to match, so I'll have to look into the circumstance of the timeframe. Perhaps an auxiliary of some sort...

Comment: @justCal -  good find!

Comment: Still not a sure thing, but a teaching college is promising.

Comment: The answer makes it clear that there appear to have been earlier incarnations of this school so arguments about when the current incarnation became co-ed or got its coat of arms [1963](https://www.heraldry-wiki.com/heraldrywiki/index.php/Felsted_School) are not a problem. She does look too young to be a trainee teacher to me though.

Comment: @DavidRobinson - perhaps "feeder" schools for teacher training, but I'm guessing ;)